# what is the distribution of min(y,x) when x is exp and y is Geometric?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

what is the distribution of min(y,x) when x is exp and y is Geometric?

and how i find the mean and median?

here are my tries:

T=min(Y,X)
Y~exp(λ)
X~Geo(p)

F$_{T}$(t)=P(T≤t)=P(min(Y,X)≤t)=1-P(min(Y,x)≥t)=1-P(Y≥t,X≥t)=1-P(Y≥t)•P(X≥t)

⇒F$_{T}$(t)=1-exp(-λ•t)•(1-p)[t]

Answer (score 1):

Some initial comments:

- The distribution of the minimum will have both continuous and discrete elements.
- You seem to be assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent
- $F_T(t)$ should be $1-P(Y \gt t, X \gt t)$ with strictly greater-than signs
- there are two slightly different types of [geomentric random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution): those which can take the value $0$, and those which have a minimum possible value of $1$
- You have not defined $[t]$

All that being said, your answer of $F_T(t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}(1-p)^{[t]}$ looks sensible for a suitable definition of $[t]$: for a geometric random variable $Y$ which must be positive it is the floor of $t$; if $Y$ can be zero then one more than this.

Comment: how can you find mean here? or median it's not derived.

Comment: In the geometric case with $Y$ positive, and considering it to be approximately exponential, I would expect the mean to be slightly more than $\frac{1}{\lambda + p}$ and the median to be roughly $\log_e(2)$ times that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the mean of the nonnegative random variable $T$ is 
$$
E(T)=\int_0^\infty P(T\geqslant t)\mathrm dt.
$$
In the present case,
$$
E(T)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}(1-p)^n\mathrm dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-p)^n\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda n}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda (n+1)}}\lambda,
$$
that is,
$$
E(T)=\frac1{1-(1-p)\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}\,\frac{1-\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}\lambda.
$$
The medians $m$ are defined by the condition 
$$F_T(m^-)\leqslant \tfrac12\leqslant F_T(m).$$ 
Let $r=1/(1-p)$. If $m=n+x$ with $0\lt x\lt 1$, one asks that
$$
\mathrm e^{\lambda(x+n)}r^n=2.
$$
If $m=n$ is an integer, one asks that
$$
\mathrm e^{\lambda n}r^{n-1}\leqslant2\leqslant\mathrm e^{\lambda n}r^{n}.
$$
Consider
$$a=\frac{\log2}{\lambda+\log r}=\frac{\log2}{\lambda-\log(1-p)},\quad b=\frac{\log2+\log r}{\lambda+\log r}=\frac{\log2-\log(1-p)}{\lambda-\log(1-p)},
$$
and note that $a$ and $b$ cannot be simultaneously integers since $a\lt b\lt a+1$.

- If $[a,b]$ contains an integer, then the median $m$ is unique and equal to this integer.
- Otherwise,  the median $m$ is unique and $m=\lfloor a\rfloor+x$ where $x$ solves $\lambda x=\log2\cdot\{a\}/a$.

Comment: Amazing! thanks...